# Toggling JCheckBox value

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcheckbox, itemlistener

im trying to toggle my jcheckbox. I have set the default to check jcb2. my jcb1 is working fine but my jcb2 can't seem to be toggled on. I added a println and found that it gets printed but my jcb2 does not get check.

```
class CheckBoxHandler implements ItemListener
{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {

        if(jcb1.isSelected()) 
        {
            jcb1.setSelected(true);
            jcb2.setSelected(false);
        }
        if(jcb2.isSelected()) 
        {
            jcb1.setSelected(false);
            jcb2.setSelected(true);
            System.out.println("1");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it because both are selected and your first `if` statement de-selects the second check box?

Comment: only 1 checkbox will be selected at anytime. with 1st checkbox checked, i could not check my 2nd checkbox unless i uncheck the 1st box. the value 1 only gets printed when i do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the first check-box is selected, they will both be selected the moment you select the second check-box. This means the first `if`-condition will be met, such that the second check-box will be deselected right away.

So instead of checking which check-boxes are selected, you should use the `ItemEvent e` to see which check-box you just selected.

```
if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
    if(e.getItem() == jcb1) {
        jcb2.setSelected(false);
    } else {
        jcb1.setSelected(false);
    }
}
```